# Regex any ASCII character

Tags: regex, ascii

What is the regex to match `xxx[any ASCII character here, spaces included]+xxx`?

I am trying `xxx[(\w)(\W)(\s)]+xxx`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you really mean *any* ASCII (e.g. not all Unicode characters):

```
xxx[\x00-\x7F]+xxx
```

JavaScript example:

```
var re = /xxx[\x00-\x7F]+xxx/;

re.test('xxxabcxxx')
// true

re.test('xxx☃☃☃xxx')
// false
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work the way I thought it would. This matches the BYTE representations of ascii characters, not the visual printed / typed characters themselves?

Comment: @advocate, yes it does.  What language did you test in?  That could be it.

Comment: oh I was hoping to find something to match the printed versions of ASCII characters :)

Comment: @advocate, I think you're looking for `^[\x20-\x7F]+$`.

Comment: Such a nice solution, I have seen so many bad ones. I was not aware about regex being able to filter by the charcode, elegant!

Comment: wrygiel - !!! :) Just a tip for removing CR LF `e.replace(/\x0A/g,"").replace(/\x0D/g,"")` (hex of 10 and 13 are 0A and 0D respectively)

Comment: @wrygiel Small correction as `x7F` is not printable (it's the `DEL` char). It should be `^[\x20-\x7E]+$`.

Answer (score 143):

```
[ -~]
```

It was [seen here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/my-favorite-regex/). It matches all ASCII characters from the space to the tilde.

So your implementation would be:

```
xxx[ -~]+xxx
```

Comment: This is perfect, since the accepted answer did not work with [RegularExpression] attribute in ASP.NET MVC - it gets rendered as Unicode chars and this breaks the validation.

Comment: Really elegant solution, highly readable and semantically exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Art This is not working for me with a `[RegularExpression]` attribute... Did you have to do anything else special for it to work? My attribute is just `<Component.DataAnnotations.RegularExpression("[ -~]", ErrorMessage:="Contains invalid characters.")>` but won't even accept "asdf".

Comment: I guess never mind. I just realized that will only match one character, so I had to add the + to make it `[ -~]+` "any ascii character, one or more times" for my usage.

Comment: @Zack check out this article I wrote with the fully working example code: http://nimblegecko.com/how-to-validate-a-textfield-for-only-printable-characters-in-aspnet-mvc/ Hope it helps and let me know if you're stuck!

Comment: @Art Yeah it is working, I just didn't think about how I would need the + on the end to make it match a character "one or more" times, and I got confused when it wouldn't accept anything I tried to test with like "qwert", "1234" etc, because they were all longer than one character.

Comment: Very helpful. I used `[^ -~]` and replace every match by empty string to remove non ASCII characters.

Comment: great answer, see live demo (space excluded) https://regex101.com/r/Xuj0Pf/1

Answer (score 36):

You can use the `[[:ascii:]]` class.

Comment: @catwalk You are my hero for today! It wasn't accepting \x00-\x7F for some reason, but it took [:ascii:]. Thanks!

Comment: Note that [[:ascii:]] would match any ASCII character, even non-printable characters, whereas [ -~] would match just the printable subset of ASCII.

Comment: *"character class"*?

Comment: Note: A better name would be "POSIX expression", instead of "class". Be aware that it is not supported in every language, for example JavaScript, does not support it.

Comment: I wish that worked in powershell.

Answer (score 11):

Since US-ASCII characters are in the byte range of 0x00–0x7F (0–127):

```
xxx[\x00-\x7F]+xxx
```

Answer (score 8):

Accepts / Matches only ASCII characters

```
/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.+` instead of `[(\w)(\W)(\s)]+`.

Note that this actually includes more than you need - ASCII only defines the first 128 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean with "ASCII character" you could simply try:

```
xxx.+xxx
```

Answer (score -2):

`.` stands for any char, so you write your regex like this:

```
xxx.+xxx
```