# ASCII non readable characters 28, 29 31

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

I am processing a file which I need to split based on the separator.

The following code shows the separators defined for the files I am processing

```
private static final String    component   = Character.toString((char) 31);
private static final String    data        = Character.toString((char) 29);
private static final String    segment     = Character.toString((char) 28);
```

Can someone please explain the significance of these specific separators?

Looking at the ASCII codes, these separators are file, group and unit separators. I don't really understand what this means.

Answer (score 34):

[Found this here. Cool website!](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/ascii-characters.html)

> 28 – FS – File separator The file
> separator FS is an interesting control
> code, as it gives us insight in the
> way that computer technology was
> organized in the sixties. We are now
> used to random access media like RAM
> and magnetic disks, but when the ASCII
> standard was defined, most data was
> serial. I am not only talking about
> serial communications, but also about
> serial storage like punch cards, paper
> tape and magnetic tapes. In such a
> situation it is clearly efficient to
> have a single control code to signal
> the separation of two files. The FS
> was defined for this purpose.
>
> 29 – GS – Group separator
> Data storage was one
> of the main reasons for some control
> codes to get in the ASCII definition.
> Databases are most of the time setup
> with tables, containing records. All
> records in one table have the same
> type, but records of different tables
> can be different. The group separator
> GS is defined to separate tables in a
> serial data storage system. Note that
> the word table wasn't used at that
> moment and the ASCII people called it
> a group.
>
> 30 – RS – Record separator
> Within a group (or table) the records
> are separated with RS or record
> separator.
>
> 31 – US – Unit separator
> The smallest data items to be stored
> in a database are called units in the
> ASCII definition. We would call them
> field now. The unit separator
> separates these fields in a serial
> data storage environment. Most current
> database implementations require that
> fields of most types have a fixed
> length. Enough space in the record is
> allocated to store the largest
> possible member of each field, even if
> this is not necessary in most cases.
> This costs a large amount of space in
> many situations. The US control code
> allows all fields to have a variable
> length. If data storage space is
> limited—as in the sixties—this is a
> good way to preserve valuable space.
> On the other hand is serial storage
> far less efficient than the table
> driven RAM and disk implementations of
> modern times. I can't imagine a
> situation where modern SQL databases
> are run with the data stored on paper
> tape or magnetic reels...

Comment: I like this answer better! It saves me reading a lot extra and addresses the question directly.

Comment: Though it would benefit just from adding the decimal ASCII codes that were given in the chosen answer. Also, since I came here to help me get rid of these codes out of a text file I saved from a chat app, giving the hex codes would be nice too: 1C, 1D, and 1F. For how to write in regex, btw, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character

Answer (score 3):

The ascii control characters range from 28-31. (0x1C to 0x1F)

```
31 Unit Separator
30 Record Separator
29 Group Separator
28 File Separator
```

Sample invocation:

```
char record_separator = 0x1F;
String s = "hello" + record_separator + "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

These characters are control characters. They're not meant to be written or read by humans, but by computers. You should treat them in your program like any other character.