# regex to remove unicode greek characters in php

Tags: php, regex

i have the following code:

```
        <?php

        $greek = "Ως ενταγμένη στο πολιτικό σύστημα της πρώην Ανατολικής Γερμανίας παρουσιάζει την Άνγκελα Μέρκελ νέο βιβλίο για την καγκελάριο, στο οποίο επισημαίνεται ότι ήταν υπεύθυνη στη νεολαία FDJ -πολιτισμού, όπως φροντίζει σταθερά να τονίσει η ίδια- αλλά και εργαζόταν στην Ακαδημία Επιστημών της ΛΔΓ -που ερμηνεύεται ως «απόδειξη» πως το καθεστώς την θεωρούσε φίλα προσκείμενη. 
        Φωνές από την αντιπολίτευση καλούν την καγκελάριο να μιλήσει πιο ανοικτά για το παρελθόν της, ενώ η ίδια τονίζει πως αυτά την συνοδεύουν εδώ και χρόνια και δεν έχει κρύψει τίποτε.
        Το βιβλίο, που έγραψαν οι δημοσιογράφοι Ραλφ Ρόιτ και Γκούντερ Λάχμαν (της Welt και της Bild) ονομάζεται «Η πρώτη ζωή της Άνγκελα Μ.» και μιλά για τα χρόνια της στη ΛΔΓ. Σε αυτό επισημαίνεται ότι η νυν καγκελάριος ήταν υπεύθυνη στην νεολαία FDJ αλλά και είχε στενές σχέσεις με την Ακαδημία Επιστημών, στην οποία η σοβιετική επιρροή ήταν ισχυρότατη.
        Όποιος, όπως η Άνγκελα Μέρκελ, πήγαινε με προγράμματα ανταλλαγής στη Μόσχα και τη δεκαετία του '80 εργαζόταν στην Ακαδημία Επιστημών της ΛΔΓ, δεν ήταν και ο νούμερο ένα εχθρός του κράτους» ανέφερε σχετικά η Άντγε Χέρμεναου από το κόμμα των Πράσινων. 
        «Αυτό το καταλαβαίνει ο καθένας άνω των 45 στα ανατολικά» είπε στο Focus, καλώντας την καγκελάριο «να μην ντρέπεται να μιλήσει ανοικτά για τη ζωή της στη ΛΔΓ».
        Ανάλογη ήταν και η «έκκληση» του Ραλφ Στέγκνερ από το SPD, ζητώντας από την καγκελάριο να εξηγήσει «τι πολιτικό ρόλο είχε στην ΛΔΓ».
        Η καγκελαρία από την πλευρά της επισημαίνει πως τίποτε από όλα αυτά δεν είναι καινούριο, ούτε δείχνει πως η Μέρκελ είχε κάποιον ουσιαστικά ενεργό ρόλο στη ΛΔΓ. Όσον αφορά τη FDJ, επανέλαβε πως δεν ήταν αμιγώς πολιτική νεολαία ούτε πρέπει να ταυτίζεται με το SED, αλλά προσέφερε έδαφος για κοινωνική δραστηριότητα.
        Η ίδια η Μέρκελ, αναφερόμενη στο θέμα σε ομιλία της το βράδυ της Κυριακής εξήγησε ήρεμα πως δεν έχει κρύψει ούτε και έχει να κρύψει τίποτε. «Όταν ανακύπτει πάντα ένα σημείο που φαινόταν διαφορετικό από την σκοπιά της παλιάς Δυτικής Γερμανίας, πάντα κάποιος βρίσκεται και λέει α, δεν μας έχει πει αυτό, δεν μας έχει πει το άλλο» είπε. 
        «Δεν ξέρω, κι άλλα πράγματα μπορεί να μην έχω πει που δεν με ρώτησε κανείς», επαναλαμβάνοντας πως δεν έχει αποκρύψει ποτέ τίποτε.";

        $name = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}\s]~u', '$1', $greek);

        echo $name;
        ?>
```

this results in this:

```
            Ως ενταγμένη στο πολιτικό σύστημα της πρώην Ανατολικής Γερμανίας παρουσιάζει την Άνγκελα Μέρκελ νέο βιβλίο για την καγκελάριο στο οποίο επισημαίνεται ότι ήταν υπεύθυνη στη νεολαία FDJ -πολιτισμού όπως φροντίζει σταθερά να τονίσει η ίδια- αλλά και εργαζόταν στην Ακαδημία Επιστημών της ΛΔΓ -που ερμηνεύεται ως απόδειξη πως το καθεστώς την θεωρούσε φίλα προσκείμενη 
            Φωνές από την αντιπολίτευση καλούν την καγκελάριο να μιλήσει πιο ανοικτά για το παρελθόν της ενώ η ίδια τονίζει πως αυτά την συνοδεύουν εδώ και χρόνια και δεν έχει κρύψει τίποτε
            Το βιβλίο που έγραψαν οι δημοσιογράφοι Ραλφ Ρόιτ και Γκούντερ Λάχμαν της Welt και της Bild ονομάζεται Η πρώτη ζωή της Άνγκελα Μ και μιλά για τα χρόνια της στη ΛΔΓ Σε αυτό επισημαίνεται ότι η νυν καγκελάριος ήταν υπεύθυνη στην νεολαία FDJ αλλά και είχε στενές σχέσεις με την Ακαδημία Επιστημών στην οποία η σοβιετική επιρροή ήταν ισχυρότατη
            Όποιος όπως η Άνγκελα Μέρκελ πήγαινε με προγράμματα ανταλλαγής στη Μόσχα και τη δεκαετία του ' εργαζόταν στην Ακαδημία Επιστημών της ΛΔΓ δεν ήταν και ο νούμερο ένα εχθρός του κράτους ανέφερε σχετικά η Άντγε Χέρμεναου από το κόμμα των Πράσινων 
            Αυτό το καταλαβαίνει ο καθένας άνω των  στα ανατολικά είπε στο Focus καλώντας την καγκελάριο να μην ντρέπεται να μιλήσει ανοικτά για τη ζωή της στη ΛΔΓ
            Ανάλογη ήταν και η έκκληση του Ραλφ Στέγκνερ από το SPD ζητώντας από την καγκελάριο να εξηγήσει τι πολιτικό ρόλο είχε στην ΛΔΓ
            Η καγκελαρία από την πλευρά της επισημαίνει πως τίποτε από όλα αυτά δεν είναι καινούριο ούτε δείχνει πως η Μέρκελ είχε κάποιον ουσιαστικά ενεργό ρόλο στη ΛΔΓ Όσον αφορά τη FDJ επανέλαβε πως δεν ήταν αμιγώς πολιτική νεολαία ούτε πρέπει να ταυτίζεται με το SED αλλά προσέφερε έδαφος για κοινωνική δραστηριότητα
            Η ίδια η Μέρκελ αναφερόμενη στο θέμα σε ομιλία της το βράδυ της Κυριακής εξήγησε ήρεμα πως δεν έχει κρύψει ούτε και έχει να κρύψει τίποτε Όταν ανακύπτει πάντα ένα σημείο που φαινόταν διαφορετικό από την σκοπιά της παλιάς Δυτικής Γερμανίας πάντα κάποιος βρίσκεται και λέει α δεν μας έχει πει αυτό δεν μας έχει πει το άλλο είπε 
            Δεν ξέρω κι άλλα πράγματα μπορεί να μην έχω πει που δεν με ρώτησε κανείς επαναλαμβάνοντας πως δεν έχει αποκρύψει ποτέ τίποτε
```

how can i be sure 100% that all characters like ", . > < / ? +- =_`1234567890 !~@#$%^&*() € etc. are removed from the text?

what regex i must use? please note that it's utf-8.

Also, is there a way to make all accent uppercase letters to match their lowercase accent letter? is there a way to make all letters lowercase?

sorry for so many questions, regex is like a mountain to me...

Comment: question 2: use the /i flag in your regexp to make it case insensitive

Comment: OT, but still, I didn't know that Merkel was a young communist!

Comment: and for question 1, I'm not sure about how it would work with greeks characters but maybe there's a hint there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character

Comment: thanks for the replies guys, please provide the whole regex if you can, i don't know where to put the /i flag.  @SST LCU lol!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
echo preg_replace('~[^\p{Greek}\s]++~u', '', $greek);
```

Comment: what if the text contains " " or .

Comment: @StathisNtonasII: all that is not a greek character or a white-space character is removed (double-quotes and dot too). If you want to preserve something, put it in the character class.

Comment: if i use this pregmatch i get only the first word. all the rest are replaced by whitespace.

Comment: @StathisNtonasII: But why do you use preg_match? I wrote preg_replace, test the code!

Comment: Sorry i meant preg_replace.