# Matching special characters

Tags: regex, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to match a list of special characters (`'-&`) for a postgresql query. Through an online regex editor I came to the pattern `[\'\-\&\\]`. But when I use that in my query I get an syntax error:

```
connection.execute("SELECT index, name FROM test21 WHERE test21.name  ~ '[\'''\-\&\\]'")
```

results ins

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: test21 WHERE test21.name  ~ '['''\-\&\]'
                                         ^
```

I found other answers, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925429/380038, but these match all special characters.

Comment: Needs to be enclosed in single-quotes...

Comment: Thanks Nicarus, add quotes, now different error.

Comment: You need to handle any inside single-quotes, too. So: `'[\'''\-\&\\]'`

Comment: updated, but still not valid.

Comment: Sorry, there was one extra quote. Should be: `'[\''\-\&\\]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with q(str) as (
    values ('abc'), ('a-b'), ('a''b'), ('a&b'), ('a\b'))

select str, str ~ '[''\-&\\]' bool
from q;

 str | bool 
-----+------
 abc | f
 a-b | t
 a'b | t
 a&b | t
 a\b | t
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Only one addition: Because of the use of sqlalchemy there has to be another '\' : `'[''\-&\\\]'` worked for me in the end as part of the python string.