# Regex Expression for english letters and special characters

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012

I want to write a regex expression which allows all the english alphabets and special characters for e.g

```
Abcdwfg*+""æ-/.,´Øøå&öé
```

And such string should not start with a number i mean number can come after any alphabet for e.g `"Héllo123"`

I tried this `[a-zA-Z\s]{0,50}` but it only accepts English small and capital letters,
than i tried  `[\w\sØÖ]{0,100}`  but in this i have to explicitly write that these `ØÖ` characters should be allowed so i need some help here.

Here is the code where i am trying to do it

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ForlagName" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid ForlagName." Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\s]{0,50}" ValidationGroup="vgForlagKey">
     </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention the [hexadecimal values or ranges](http://character-code.com/) for special character in regex character class and repeat the same regex again along with `0-9` to avoid starting of any string from any digit.

For example:

```
[A-Za-z\xf6-\xf8\xe5]+[A-Za-z\xf6-\xf8\xe50-9]*
```

Some example for hexadecimal values and their special character

```
f6 - ö 
f7 - ÷
f8 - ø
e5 - å
...
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/wK9xF6/2)

**Note:** Use `^` and `$` for matching starting and ending of the string/line if needed.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[\D]{0,50}
```

\D is everything thats not a digit.