# Regex match between regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the anchor in a URL, where the anchor (#text) can be in these formats:

```
https://example.com/#section3?a=1a&b=2b
https://example.com/#section3&a=1a&b=2b
https://example.com/?a=1a&b=2b#section3
https://example.com/&a=1a&b=2b#section3
```

So I would have to get the following in all cases:

```
#section3
```

Anchors in the URL [can only contain ASCII characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars), so I though [this could be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203210/1081396) for that.

I got this, and although it seems to work, it seems to be it can be done better and shorter?

```
#(.)*\?|#(.)*?\&|#(.)*
```

Comment: Why not split on anchors and then strip until you got the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood your question then this is one of many solution.

```
#([^?&\s]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/asDvr6/1