# Split a dataframe column on non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, pandas, non-ascii-characters

This is a column with data and non ascii characters

```
Summary 1

United Kingdom - �â��Global Consumer Technology - �â��American Express 
United Kingdom - �â��VP Technology - Founder - �â��Hogarth Worldwide
Aberdeen - �â��SeniorCore Analysis Specialist - �â��COREX Group
London, - �â��ED, Equit Technology, London - �â��Morgan Stanley
United Kingdom - �â��Chief Officer, Group Technology - �â��BP
```

How split them and save in different column

The code i used is:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/dataminer.csv", sep='\s*\+.*?-\s*')
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Profile URL", "Summary 1", "Summary 2"]

df.to_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv")
```

Comment: Your CSV and the code that loads it don't have much in common...

Comment: huge data in csv i have only given a column !

Answer (score 2):

Say, you have a column in a series like this:

```
s

0    United Kingdom - �â��Global Consumer Technolog...
1    United Kingdom - �â��VP Technology - Founder -...
2    Aberdeen - �â��SeniorCore Analysis Specialist ...
3    London, - �â��ED, Equit Technology, London - �...
4    United Kingdom - �â��Chief Officer, Group Tech...
Name: Summary 1, dtype: object
```

**Option 1**
Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character), you can split on non-ascii characters using `str.split`:

```
s.str.split(r'-\s*[^\x00-\x7f]+', expand=True)

                 0                                 1                  2
0  United Kingdom        Global Consumer Technology    American Express
1  United Kingdom           VP Technology - Founder   Hogarth Worldwide
2        Aberdeen    SeniorCore Analysis Specialist         COREX Group
3         London,      ED, Equit Technology, London      Morgan Stanley
4  United Kingdom   Chief Officer, Group Technology                  BP
```

---

**Option 2**
`str.extractall` + `unstack`:

```
s.str.extractall('([\x00-\x7f]+)')[0].str.rstrip(r'- ').unstack()

match               0                                1                  2
0      United Kingdom       Global Consumer Technology   American Express
1      United Kingdom          VP Technology - Founder  Hogarth Worldwide
2            Aberdeen   SeniorCore Analysis Specialist        COREX Group
3             London,     ED, Equit Technology, London     Morgan Stanley
4      United Kingdom  Chief Officer, Group Technology                 BP
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED split does not  work on my system is there any other way.

Comment: @VipulRao Can you see my edit? Why is it that my answers don't work on only your machine? :/

Comment: @coldspeed yeah i saw the edit but it does not work on my pc pandas is up to date and python3 is also installed can someone help me with this.

Comment: @VipulRao How am I supposed to help you? Can I sudo into your machine and write your code for you? Cmon, please try and at least figure out _why_ it doesn't work. You did the same thing with your last question.

Comment: @coldspeed yeah ill figure it out and thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach :

```
a
0   United Kingdom - �â��Global Consumer Technolog...
1   United Kingdom - �â��VP Technology - Founder -...
2   Aberdeen - �â��SeniorCore Analysis Specialist ...
3   London, - �â��ED, Equit Technology, London - �...
4   United Kingdom - �â��Chief Officer, Group Tech...
```

Use this  function to extract assci char (where Unicode code point  is superior to 128 ) using [ord](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) build-in function

```
def extract_ascii(x):
    string_list = filter(lambda y : ord(y) < 128, x)
    return ''.join(string_list)
```

and apply it to columns.

```
df1.a.apply(extract_ascii).str.split('-', expand=True)
```

here is the results :

```
             0          1                              2           3
0   United Kingdom  Global Consumer Technology  American Express    None
1   United Kingdom  VP Technology   Founder Hogarth Worldwide
2   Aberdeen    SeniorCore Analysis Specialist  COREX Group None
3   London, ED, Equit Technology, London    Morgan Stanley  None
4   United Kingdom  Chief Officer, Group Technology BP  None
```