# Search for non-printable characters (Carriage Return, Tab, etc.) in code editor of IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, replace, non-printing-characters

In the code editor of IntelliJ 2018, using either menu item:

- `Edit` > `Find` > `Find…`
- `Edit` > `Find` > `Replace…`

[image]

…how can I find invisible (non-printing) characters?

I am referring to characters such as:

- CARRIAGE RETURN
- LINE FEED
- [INFORMATION SEPARATOR ONE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enabling "Regex" checkbox, [you can use the full regex syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character). I was able to search for spaces with `\u0020` and for LF with `\x0a`.

- Carriage return and line feed match `\r` and `\n` respectively.
- Arbitrary Unicode character syntax: `\uFFFF`, where FFFF is a hex Unicode character code.
- Arbitrary ASCII character syntax: `\xFF`, where FF is an ASCII hex code.

Comment: For completeness, after enabling Regex checkbox, what *exactly* would you type to search for a single specific Unicode code point? I am not Regex-savvy, and your linked page confused me further.

Comment: Updated, this should be it.

Comment: This works. For example, I was able to use the "Replace all" button after enabling "Regex" checkbox to replace every occurrence of `\n>` in quoted-block-text with `\n\n>` to accomplish double-spacing-between-lines. Thanks.

Comment: Victor (or Basil's edit?) is wrong: `CR = carriage return = decimal 13 = hex 0d`, while `LF = line feed = decimal 10 = hex 0a`. See [this code chart](https://theasciicode.com.ar/).  I am currently using the latest version of IntelliJ, 2018.3.2.  Using that version, `\n` or `\x0a` finds line feeds.  However, neither `\r` nor `\x0d` finds carriage returns.  Yet I know that my file has both!  TextPad finds both, and IntelliJ itself displays that my file's line endings are CRLF.  Is this an IntelliJ bug?

Comment: Updated the answer.
Indeed it doesn't work in the current version. I filed a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204958

Comment: Victor: many thanks for filing the bug report!  I think that you still need to edit your answer, however.  I suggest: Line feed should match `\n` or `\x0a` while carriage return should match `\r` or `\x0d`.

Comment: You could also note that other regular expression engines have slight variations here.  For example, the text editor TextPad treats `\n` and `\r` identically: both match either a line feed, a carriage return, or a combined (DOS style) carriage return followed by a line feed.

Comment: You're a Lifesaver ! Thanks a lot. But only `\u200` worked and not \u200\