# Regex to match a word used with any font or case

Tags: regex

Here's what I want:
a regex expression that can match the word "hello" in any font and case. So it would match Hello, heLLo, HelLo, , , etc.

This is for a Discord bot that is written in Javascript, but I enter the regex via commands on Discord.

I feel like I'm close with Unicode, but can't quite find an answer. I'm very new to this, but here are the resources I've already explored:
[Regular expression to match non-ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-ascii-characters)
[Regex any ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character)
https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

I've used `[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]{h}` but it doesn't match the strange fonts.

Comment: You can build the expression using some Unicode service, as https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl.

Comment: Is this question solved? If not please give a full list of hello's to match.

Comment: @Kendle I just ended up adding all the different fonts.

Answer (score 0):

This matches all of your samples.

```regex
/([^\x00-\x7F]?\w?)/"ug
```